# unable to find slider coding in Magento

Tags: php, javascript

I have Magento website which is using "crappy coded" theme and uses grep for slider. Slider coding is using glider.js.

when I validate website through w3c there are some errors and one of them is related with the slider which is some thing like below:

document type does not allow element "a" here; missing one of "object", "span", "bdo", "applet", "iframe", "tt", "i", "b", "u", "s", "strike", "big", "small", "font", "em", "strong", "dfn", "code", "q", "samp", "kbd", "var", "cite", "abbr", "acronym", "sub", "sup", "label", "ins", "del" start-tag Blockquote

Here is the link of the w3 validator file showing error on line no : 525

I want to know whether is there anyway to edit the code of slider in homepage?

Comment: Just because it envolves magento does not mean it's a question about magento

Comment: However, hunting down the files where Magento stores its bits, is; so that it can then proceed to not being a question about Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Five ways to hunt for this content:

1. Have a look at CMS=>Pages for the Home Page entry and check under the **content tab** to see if they included the code there.
2. Have a look at CMS=>Pages for the Home Page entry and check under the **design tab** in either **Layout Update XML** text area  to see if they included a reference to a code block that contains the code. The path to the block will be included in the **template=** tag
3. Look through the custom theme's Layout XML files to see if there's a reference to the slider block
4. Turn on **Template Path Hints** by going to System=>Configuration, setting the Configuration Scope dropdown to a lower level than default config and then clicking the **Developer** tab near the bottom left menu. You then open the Debug window shade and set **Template Path Hints** to yes, clear cache and check the front end for the hinting as to what blocks are being used to display the slider. **Note:** to turn off, set to no and clear cache
5. Professionals would ask if the site has SSH enabled, view source on the applicable frontend page, look for output that would be hard coded in the block, go to `app/design/frontend/default` and `grep -R "uniqueContentHere" *` to immediately find the unknown phtml file from a third party content developer.

If it's in a .phtml file, ftp download the file, save a copy for backup and modify to correct the issues. Upload corrected copy, clear cache and it should be fixed.